# jQuery .on not working after ajax delete and div refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

On a page with a tab control, each tab contains a table, each tr contains a td with a button which has a value assigned to it.

```
<td>
 <button type="button" class="btn" name="deleteEventBtn" value="1">Delete</button>
</td>
```

This code below works for the first delete. After the AJAX call & the refresh of the div, no further delete buttons can be clicked. The .on is attached to the document. The same happens if I attach it to the body or anything closer to the buttons.

```
function deleteRecord(url, id, container) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: { id: id },
        success: function (data) {         
            $('#delete-popup').hide();
            $(container).trigger('refresh');
        }
    }); 
}

$(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click', '[name^="delete"]', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).val();
            $('#current-record-id').val(id);
            $('#delete-popup').modal('show');
        });

        $('#delete-btn-yes').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();          
            var recordId = $('#current-record-id').val();
            var recordType = location.hash;
            switch (recordType) {
                case "#personList":
                    deleteRecord(url, recordId, recordType);
            break;
            }
        });
});
```

Any ideas? Could it be related to the wildcard for starts with [name^="delete"]? There are no other elements where the name starts with 'delete'.

**EDIT**

When replacing

```
$(container).trigger('refresh');
```

with

```
location.reload();
```

it "works", however that refreshes the whole page, loses the users position and defeats the point of using AJAX.

Comment: Your  `switch` is missing a curly brace at the end.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that. It got accidentally deleted when removing all the other case statements, which are not relevant for this example.

Comment: Put an alert inside the delete button click and see if it appears every time you click on it.

Comment: if you are using the `.on()` function - you shouldn't need to place it inside `$(document).ready()` just use `$(document).on('click', 'selector', function())` - Also, check to make sure you selector is correct, does your Ajax function finish posting?

Answer (score 0):

As the button click is firing at first attempt, there is no issue in that code. All you have to do is, put the button click event in a method and call it after the refresh. This way, the events will be attached to the element again. See the code below,

```js
function deleteRecord(url, id, container) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: { id: id },
        success: function (data) {         
            $('#delete-popup').hide();
            $(container).trigger('refresh');
          BindEvents();
        }
    }); 
}

$(document).ready(function () {
        BindEvents();
});

function BindEvents()
{
  $(document).on('click', '[name^="delete"]', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).val();
            $('#current-record-id').val(id);
            $('#delete-popup').modal('show');
        });

        $('#delete-btn-yes').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();          
            var recordId = $('#current-record-id').val();
            var recordType = location.hash;
            switch (recordType) {
                case "#personList":
                    deleteRecord(url, recordId, recordType);
            break;
        });
  }
```

Comment: You're binding the same event multiple times to `document` if you do it this way. If `#delete-btn-yes` is getting removed then he would need to rebind that event, but I don't think it is.

Comment: Thanks, this solution results in the same behaviour.

Comment: There is no HTML, so you can't use the code snippet feature if there is nothing to "run".

Answer (score 0):

Apologies to all and thanks for your answers. The problem was due to the way the popup was being shown & hidden.

```
$('#delete-popup').modal('show');
```

and

```
$('#delete-popup').hide();
```

When I changed this line to:

```
$('#delete-popup').modal('hide');
```

it worked. Thanks to LShetty, the alert (in the right place) did help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap Modal
After Ajax Request before Refreshing page add

```
$('.modal').modal('hide');
```

This Line will Close your Modal and reload your page. Before that it will complete all Ajax Request things.

But for google chrome there is no issues :) hope this help someone.